# Show that the series $1/(n^2+1)$ is in the range below

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

By integral test I found its converges to $\frac\pi4$ but thats the only thing I can find :( Hope somebody can give me a clue about how can I handle this question.

Show that
$$\frac{\pi}{4}\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+1}\leq\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: An integral test only can decide if it converges, it can't give you the sum.

Comment: Do you know application of integration as limit of a sum?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$$\int_{n-1}^n\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+1}\leq\frac1{n^2+1}\leq
\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+1}<\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{{\lfloor x \rfloor}^2+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+1}<\int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{{\lfloor x \rfloor}^2+1}+\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x-1)^2+1}$$
$$\implies\frac{\pi}{4}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+1}<\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}$$
I suggest you look closely at the graphs of $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$, $\frac{1}{{\lfloor x \rfloor}^2+1}$, and $\frac{1}{(x-1)^2+1}$ to see why that works